# Modifying a file after "git add"

Tags: git

**Scenario**

Due to PHPMD and PHPCS checks that run during a commit, I often need to modify files that have already been affected by "git add".

If I modify a file that is added, and retry the commit, the changes aren't recognized, so the commit will fail again.

I then need to "git reset" the files to un-add them, then re-"git add" them and run the commit again.

**Question**

Is there a way to update the files that are staged for a commit, without having to un-add and re-ad them?

*I apologize if this is a duplicate. All my searches seem to only show results for different problems with similar words.*

Comment: Just `git add` them again. You don't need to reset them.

Comment: Git itself is perfectly fine with re-`git add`-ing a file after an aborted commit (I'm guessing you have a pre-commit hook that stops the commit).  Perhaps there is some issue with your check script.

Comment: @torek - You're right about the commit being aborted before it actually does anything. Thanks!

Comment: @Zeeker - Perfect. Didn't even consider that, but it works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In git, files (per se) aren't staged, changes are. So when you do `git add <filename>`, it is the *current state* of that file that is staged. If you change the file and want to add those changes as well, you just do another `git add`.

Answer (score 9):

You just `git add` the file again and commit.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't really consider this because even after I performed the new changes, the files were still in green (i.e. still staged).

Answer (score 5):

> Is there a way to update the files that are staged for a commit,
>   without having to un-add and re-ad them?

No need to Un-add and re-add them

Just again add that file

```
git add file
```

---

After modifying any added file when you see `git status -s`

```
MM filename
```

so when you again add it then it will become

```
git add filename
git status -s
M  filename
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in other answers and by yourself, `git add` should work. However, I think you already have a valid commit (which was not passing some test) and with another `git add` and `git commit`, you are just adding a new commit to your branch. The falty one still exsits and fail. There are a bunch of solution you can do here. Just two examples coming into my head at the moment:

```
git rebase --interactive HEAD~2
```

This gives you a editor window where you can squash your two commits into one. Just change the pick in front of your second commit to f or s and save the file.

Another way could be to use `git commit --amend`

This will allow you to modify last commit. However, I recommend to read documentation for both.

Comment: Good advice (but do read the manual).  In general,  if one single, or two commits is appropriate depends on what the second change was; a correction of the first, or separate enough to warrant its own commit message.

Comment: Good stuff. The Mess Detector and Code Sniffer invalidate the commit before it's executed, so no commits are actually run, and the changes are still staged when this happens.